# How to create a shortcut using a batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, shortcuts

How can I create a shortcut to the file `D:\myfile.extension` on the Desktop using a batch script?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719977/111036) I just posted, which calls a line of powershell from a batch script.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can achieve without external tools this by creating a temporary VBScript:

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\myshortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "D:\myfile.extension" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

(Idea taken from [here](http://ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html).)

This will create `myshortcut.lnk` on the Desktop, pointing to `D:\myfile.extension`.

You can supply additional properties before saving the link by modifying the following values:

```
oLink.Arguments
oLink.Description
oLink.HotKey
oLink.IconLocation
oLink.WindowStyle
oLink.WorkingDirectory
```

Consult [How to create a desktop shortcut with the Windows Script Host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244677) to see a few examples.

Comment: Is it impossible to do with batch script? (apart from generating your proposed vbs and executing it)

Comment: Is there a way to set `AppUserModelId` using this method?

Comment: Note that this can be modified to use relative paths (quite likely if this is being done via a script). The `sLinkFile` can be a relative path (e.g. just providing "myshortcut.lnk" puts it in the current directory). The target file can be set relative to the current directory by specifying `oLink.TargetPath = "%cd%\folder\target.exe"`.

Comment: Notify, that name of Desktop folder is language dependent.

Answer (score 18):

```
@echo off
echo [InternetShortcut] >> "%AllUsersProfile%\desktop\NOTEPAD.url"
echo URL="C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE" >> "%AllUsersProfile%\desktop\NOTEPAD.url"
echo IconFile=C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll >> "%AllUsersProfile%\desktop\NOTEPAD.url"
echo IconIndex=20 >> "%AllUsersProfile%\desktop\NOTEPAD.url"
```

This code creates a shortcut in the "All Users" desktop folder called NOTEPAD.url pointing to the NotePad application, and will also assign an icon from the SHELL32.dll. Change the path and filename to your D:/ location and exename. And make sure your .url filename stays the same across all lines of code.

Comment: Nice idea. As long as you don't have to supply any arguments, this works well.

Answer (score 6):

there is external command shortcut.exe that can do this in that way:

```
shortcut /a:c /f:"c:\users\me\desktop\myshortcut.lnk" /t:"c:\program files\skype\skype.exe"
```

that can create shortcut of skype in your desktop

it is free downloadable program, but i can't find its link, so i will try to upload it and post the link

---

**here it is**:

[shortcut.exe by Marty List](http://optimumx.com/download/Shortcut.zip)

Comment: no, i didn't know that there is utility for it in resource kit by microsoft. i am currenlty using its alternative by optimum x