# How come adding desktop icon with shortcut.exe no longer works?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, batch-file

Here's the code from a batch file:

```
@echo off
rem add desktop icon 
"C:\Program Files\shortcut.exe" /f:"%userprofile%\desktop\Knowledge NoteBook.lnk" /a:c /t:"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" /p:"http://127.0.0.1:8600/knb2/index.cfm?more=1" /i:"C:\Program Files\kn12.ico" /r:1 /d:"Knowledge NoteBook"
```

that used to work for the last two years under Windows XP, Vista and 7.  But lately when I try it with Windows 7 Professional it does not do anything and I don't receive any error messages.  I even turned off AV. All required files are in the correct paths.

Comment: I would be surprised if that old NT Resource Kit utility still worked in 7. You could try doing something similar with [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

Comment: try using one of these methods instead: How to create a shortcut using a batch script... http://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script/455398#455398