# How to create Windows 7 shortcut files through command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a shortcut using a batch script?](https://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script)

I would like to create shortcut files from some commands on a batch file.

Currently, I create .bat files for such each shortcut, but I would like to create .lnk files instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can either use a third-party program or create a temporary `.vbs` script. See the answers here: [How to create a shortcut using a batch script?](http://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script)

Comment: Do you mean create shortcuts to execute command prompt commands, or create a shortcut *from* a command prompt command? Edit: Oh, forgot what your title said. Yeah, what Dennis said is the only way to do it. I ran into this exact problem a while back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, never use %username% to get a user's profile path.

You should use the environment variable USERPROFILE instead of the 
username, because sometimes the user profile path contains more than 
just the username (e.g. ., .000, 
.windows)

Back to your issue:

You cannot create a shortcut by just copy the exe file.

You can use a VBScript to create the shortcut:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!msg/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/-RgWWk62aAE/qQ_u5sg8zOgJ

Alternatively:

Some free command line tools for shortcut creation:

Marty List's shortcut.exe 
http://optimumx.com/download/#Shortcut

MakeScut

http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/scriptingtoolkit/Default.asp