# How to create a desktop shortcut from a batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch, shortcuts, vbscript, arguments

I know there are many posts on this issue but there is a minor twist to what I need to do.

I can figure out how to create a shortcut with an argument like this:
`"C:\Program Files\My App\App.exe" /s`

But I need to apply the path of a file wrapped in "" as argument like this:
`"C:\Program Files\My App\App.exe" "c:\Data\File.ext"`
Note the double quotes.

I can't find any VBscript examples illustrating this behaviour.
This is what I've based my current script on.

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\myshortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "D:\myfile.extension" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

Comment: What code/method are you currently using to create your shortcut?  BTW: VBScript != Batch File

Comment: @techie007 - I am aware. I am calling a temporary VBScript from within the batch file. Something like this http://superuser.com/a/455383/257686

Comment: Here check this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

The soultion was the triple quotes:

For some reason the

> echo oLink.arguments = Chr(34) & "c:\Data\File 1.ext" & Chr(34)

Makes the File 1.ext open.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`echo oLink.arguments = "c:\Data\File.ext"`

Before the oLink.save.

If you find you still need to include the quotes (I don't think you would), you can triple them up in the batch file.

`echo oLink.arguments = """c:\Data\File 1.ext"""`

The outer-most quotes are the ones delimiting the string, and the inner doubled up double quotes are to put the double quote within the string.

Comment: I need the quotes as the App.exe splits the argument if it contains spaces. I.e. C:\Data\File 1.ext

Comment: @MortenKahr Usually I use Chr(34) instead of double quotes for the outer pair as shown [on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4192714/935614)

Comment: @nixda So echo oLink.arguments = Chr(34) c:\Data\File 1.ext Chr(34) ?

Comment: @MortenKahr `echo oLink.arguments = Chr(34) & "c:\Data\File 1.ext" & Chr(34)`

Comment: Adjusted my answer (after testing).

Comment: @nixda (techie007) I'll try both in the morning. Thanks a lot