# Create many shortcuts (.lnk) of existing files and add target arguments to all shortcuts

Tags: windows, powershell, file-shortcut

I have a folder with 1000 .bin files in. I would like help with finding a PowerShell command to create set of shortcuts to these files with a static set of **command line parameters** in the shortcut's 'Target', namely a program (C:\prog.exe), an argument (-X), a file (dll.dll) and finally the filename (randomly_named_file.bin)

[A shortcut with target arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxrA1.png)

```
"C:\prog.exe" -X "C:\dll.dll" "C:\folder\file_0001.bin"
```

If I highlight all the .bin files in the folder and right-click-drag to the target folder and select 'create shortcut here', I get 1000+ shortcuts where in 'Target' it just has the filename. I need to create 1000+ shortcuts all with the same target arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a shortcut using a batch script?](https://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found help elsewhere on The Internet!

Here's a simple, elegant PowerShell script that can bulk create billions of shortcuts and append target arguments to all of them, whilst keeping the filename/location at the end of the set of target arguments:

PS C:\folder\where\files\are\kept>

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
$original = '"' + $_.FullName + '"'
$link     = 'C:\folder\where\files\are\kept' + $_.BaseName + '.lnk'
$wshell   = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $wshell.CreateShortcut($link)
$shortcut.TargetPath = 'C:\prog.exe'
$shortcut.Arguments = '-X "C:\dll.dll" ' + $original
$shortcut.Save()
}
```

It was the **+ $original** bit that I was looking for. Hooray.