# Create a shortcut using batch with quotes in the Target

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, shortcuts

Based on: [How to create a shortcut using a batch script?](https://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script?newreg=766bf739ddb3446a87b8e5289df7ebcc)

I can't figure out how to write this batch so all the quotes are in the right place and create the shortcut file. I used the above info as reference.
My final target should be

```
Target: %COMSPEC% /c start "" "E:\PinballEmporium\Core\RetroFE.exe"
```

This is the batch I've wrote, if I remove everything after the word 'start' it will write the shortcut file, but obviously that's not all I need. (This is being launched from 'E:\PinballEmporium')

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Pinball Emporium.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%

REM %COMSPEC% /c start "" "E:\PinballEmporium\Core\RetroFE.exe"
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%%COMSPEC%% /c start "" "%cd%\Core\RetroFE.exe"" >> %SCRIPT%
REM echo oLink.Arguments="%cd%\Core\RetroFE.exe" >> %SCRIPT%

echo oLink.IconLocation="%cd%\PEICON.ico" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory="%cd%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WindowStyle="0" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Description="Shortcut for Pinball Emporium"
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try for this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Title Batch Shortcut Creator
Set "ShortcutName=Pinball Emporium"
Set "TargetPath=E:\PinballEmporium\Core\RetroFE.exe"
Set "IconLocation=%cd%\PEICON.ico"
Call :Create_Shortcut "%ShortcutName%" "%TargetPath%" "%IconLocation%"
EXIT
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Create_Shortcut
Set "VBS_Shortcut=%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
>"%VBS_Shortcut%" (
    echo    Call Create_Shortcut("%~1","%~2","%~3"^)
    echo    Sub Create_Shortcut(ShortcutName,TargetPath,IconLocation^)
    echo        Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut
    echo        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo        DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
    echo        Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& ShortcutName ^& ".lnk"^)
    echo        objShortCut.TargetPath = chr(34^) ^& TargetPath ^& chr(34^)
    echo        objShortCut.IconLocation="%~3"
    echo        objShortCut.Save
    echo    End Sub
)
cscript //nologo "%VBS_Shortcut%" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"
If Exist "%VBS_Shortcut%" Del "%VBS_Shortcut%" 
Exit /B
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```